# I didn't have enough time, however, I read the book till the end

Tags: grammar, adverbs, syntax, semantics

This sentence is from an exercise ('use "However' to join the sentences : 'I didn't have enough time. I read the book till the end.'):

**' I didn't have enough time, however, I read the book till the end.'**
(no context provided)

They actually meant **''I was pressed for time, and had to cut down on other planned activities...'** but in the absence of context 'enough time' would refer to 'read', wouldn't it?

My question is, how could this person read the book till the end if he didn't have enough time (for it???) ?

What's the probability of this interpretation:
**'I didn't have enough time to read the book thoroughly. I read it cursorily'** ?

Comment: It depends on the context. Someone wouldn't just walk up to you in the street and say "I didn't have enough time, however, I read the book till the end." But if you were a teacher and asked one of your pupils "Have you written your book report?" they might reply: "I didn't have enough time, however, I read the book till the end." But if you're doing an exercise, does it matter? Why are you actually asking this and what do you *really* want to know or prove? We can't answer a question you don't ask.

Comment: The sentence means "I managed to read the whole book despite there not being enough time," and anything outside of that is not contained in the sentence. Just how the speaker managed the self-proclaimed impossible task is not part of the sentence, and the listener is free to imagine any scenario they like, depending on their preconceived notions of the speaker.

Comment: @StuartF I wanted to know if the most likely (and obvious?) interpretation of  I didn't have enough time, however, I read the book till the end.'  would be 'I was pressed for time, and had to cut down on other planned activities, however, I read the book till the end.'

Comment: It could mean that the speaker spent time reading  that could/should have been spent doing something else.

Comment: @KateBunting So 'I didn't have enough time' was actually an ellipsys.

Comment: @Didyougo It's definitely ellipsis; the only question is what is omitted, what they "didn't have enough time" for. The only thing mentioned in the sentence is the book, but this seems contradictory. It's possible it refers to something else, or it's possible it refers to the book in some way that resolves the contradiction. You've suggested several such ways.

Comment: Still another possibility is that whoever constructed the sentence really meant "I didn't have *much* time," and made an error in usage.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning is created by context. Since this sentence has no context, its meaning is obscured (and it makes a poor choice for an example!). It does contain an apparent contradiction. If we wanted to imagine a context that might make sense, it *could* be an response to something like "Did you write a report on the assigned book?", in which "I didn't have time" refers to some other activity besides finishing the reading.

Don't worry if it's hard to find meaning in sentences or phrases that are taken out of context. Real human communication happens in context. Either ignore the lack of clarity, or entertain yourself inventing scenarios that would fit them (like the [illustrated edition of *The Elements of Style*](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/elements-of-style-illustrated-william-strunk/1007727661), which amplifies the intriguing out-of-context sample sentences into watercolor paintings).

EDIT: You proposed an interpretation that reconciles the apparent contradiction. "I didn't have enough time"—if that means "I didn't have enough time to read the book," then how did the speaker do it after all? As long as we're speculating about meanings, one *could* be "I didn't have enough time to read the whole book, but I made extra time by moving my schedule around and read it all anyway." People do sometimes speak in this "you must do the impossible" way, like on *Star Trek*, in which the engineer insists that he's giving the ship all the speed possible, and the captain insists that he find more somehow.

Comment: Shall we tell the poor schoolchild who posted this out-of-context task on https://znanija.com/task/54615045 that this is a very poorly constructed exercise that seems to be actually aimed at dumbing down the student?

Comment: @Didyougo Well, "*very* poorly constructed" seems a bit severe, and I certainly wouldn't assume that a school assignment actually maliciously intended to lower the student's intelligence. Maybe there's more on that page in cyrillic that is lost on me, but unless the student is in great distress, I wouldn't feel any obligation to speak up.

Comment: @Didyougo I'm going to edit: your proposed meaning is not impossible.